# Issues with creating files for npx create-react-app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

Very new to web development, this is my second day actually and already ran into some problems.  I tried to create react app and received this string of messages ...

npx create-react-app playground
npx: installed 67 in 10.19s

Creating a new React app in C:\Users\rszym\playground.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

> core-js@2.6.12 postinstall C:\Users\rszym\playground\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js@3.9.1 postinstall C:\Users\rszym\playground\node_modules\core-js
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> core-js-pure@3.9.1 postinstall C:\Users\rszym\playground\node_modules\core-js-pure
> node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"

> ejs@2.7.4 postinstall C:\Users\rszym\playground\node_modules\ejs
> node ./postinstall.js

- cra-template@1.1.2
- react@17.0.1
- react-dom@17.0.1
- react-scripts@4.0.3
  added 1915 packages from 725 contributors and audited 1918 packages in 126.17s

131 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Git repo not initialized Error: Command failed: git --version
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:630:11)
at execSync (child_process.js:666:15)
at tryGitInit (C:\Users\rszym\playground\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:46:5)
at module.exports (C:\Users\rszym\playground\node_modules\react-scripts\scripts\init.js:283:7)
at [eval]:3:14
at Script.runInThisContext (vm.js:120:18)
at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:309:38)
at Object. ([eval]-wrapper:10:26)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1137:30)
at evalScript (internal/process/execution.js:94:25) {
status: 1,
signal: null,
output: [ null, null, null ],
pid: 9548,
stdout: null,
stderr: null
}

Installing template dependencies using npm...
npm WARN tsutils@3.20.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-server\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

- @testing-library/jest-dom@5.11.9
- web-vitals@1.1.0
- @testing-library/user-event@12.8.1
- @testing-library/react@11.2.5
  added 29 packages from 78 contributors and audited 1947 packages in 23.653s

131 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Removing template package using npm...

npm WARN tsutils@3.20.0 requires a peer of typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >=

3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta but none is

installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\watchpack-

chokidar2\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted

{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted

{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\webpack-dev-

server\node_modules\fsevents):

npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted

{"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

removed 1 package and audited 1946 packages in 13.778s

131 packages are looking for funding
run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities

Success! Created playground at C:\Users\rszym\playground
Inside that directory, you can run several commands:

npm start
Starts the development server.

npm run build
Bundles the app into static files for production.

npm test
Starts the test runner.

npm run eject
Removes this tool and copies build dependencies, configuration files
and scripts into the app directory. If you do this, you can’t go back!

We suggest that you begin by typing:

cd playground
npm start

Happy hacking!

I know it says successful but could someone help explain what everything else means?

Thanks

Comment: what ***problems***??  "I know it says successful but..." seems to suggest that you haven't even tried anything to verify that things are working.  What are you actually asking for help **fixing**??

Comment: Thanks for the response Claies. You’re right I didn’t check, it was working. I worded my question poorly, I was trying to ask what the warning, initializing failures, and skipping optional dependencies meant.

Answer (score 0):

`npm` is just skipping the install for the optional dependency `fsevents` because it is not compatible with Windows. It's **optional** so it doesn't really matter if it installs or not.